# How do I get my Apple Mighty Mouse to work on PPC edition?

Tags: mouse

I had some trouble pairing the device but I finally got it to pair.

So far, only the mouse cursor and the scroll wheel work.  When I try to click, it doesn't work.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 powerpc edition and a PowerBook G4.  The mouse is a Mighty Mouse, not a Magic Mouse.